# Why in Django models image, Media.url returns a empty string, rather than image link?

Tags: django, django-templates

Whenever I try to image.url function I get an empty string. I also tried the image.path but didn't help. I am using Django 2.15. and I have a Image field in models. My {{MEDIA_URL}}  returns /media.

I have done Django the config for setting media root, and media url in settings. py also URL pattern.

When I go to the link foo.com/media/imagefile.png it loads perfectly fine. But when I pass through views functions a dictionary

```
render (request ,templatepath,object.__dict__)
```

and in template type

```
 {{img.url}}
```

I get a empty string.
where as I want to see the real image, or its url mentioned.
Any help is appreciated.
This is what I have in urls.py

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution, The problem was caused because I passed the template a regular dictionary. Dictionary object with key img has just image name stored as a value, thus it has no url function to return. In order to solve this problem I just passed the whole query dictionary which had python objects and necessary function and variables like '.url'  in the image field.

example

```
objectpassed = Class.object.all()
render(request,templatepath,{ 'somename':objectpassed}
```